# Do libraries exist for building operating systems?

Tags: operating-system

So I'm curious about this. I assume the building of operating systems is a monumental task, especially with all the back end stuff that an os involves. I was curious if I wanted to rework the front end of an operating system, but take advantage of existing architecture/backend, what would be the best resources to use? Also, can you guys point to any examples of well designed front ends of operating systems that aren't really mainstream? It seems like everyone uses pretty large well known OS.

Comment: It's called a kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. But like you said, it's a huge, huge task. I am not sure of windows or mac, but in Linux you have options to do so. You can download a Kernel from https://www.kernel.org/ and write applications around it.

If your goal is to make applications around the kernel, then look at linux application development resources. Check out linux desktop environments https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment#History_and_common_use to see which one is good.